# Is there a flat theme that does not mess up some UIs?

Tags: unity, 16.04, themes, gui

Yesterday, i had to reinstall Ubuntu. I was looking for flat themes to put on it. I found Iris, liked it, but it messed up the UIs of OBS, GIMP, LibreOffice, and Qalculate. Basically, it makes them look like this:

[image: In GIMP]

In GIMP ^

[image]

In Qalculate ^

I don't like it because it looks like the Windows Classic theme (from Windows ME and older) And it is aesthetically unpleasing. It's very hard to see where everything is, and it **definitely** does **not** look flat.

Can anyone please show a theme that doesn't make things look ugly?

P.S. I already tried Flattastic and it did much worse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Flatabulous` theme and icon pack:

https://github.com/anmoljagetia/Flatabulous

Follow the instructions inside and don't forget to download the icon pack as well to make your Ubuntu awesome.

Comment: It's better not to use "try" in an answer. "Try" implies a suggestion and suggestions should go in comments.